# How to generate Y-axis Grid line on subchart in c3-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, c3.js

I am working with 'regions' in c3-charts. However, they don't seem to work with 'zoom' functionality.
There is a marker(single y-axis grid line) in my code, that differentiates the 2 regions. But once zoomed, when that marker is out of zoom-domain, user won't be able to identify the regions.

I would like to know, if I can generate the same marker(y-axis grid line) on the subchart. This way, user can know the region, even when the marker is not in the zoom domain.

[Image(with regions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxdbZ.jpg)

[Image(without regions, with marker and zoom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42LIj.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code so far in a codesanbox.io?

Comment: I can't access 'codesandbox.io', but here is my jsfiddle. "https://jsfiddle.net/mshardul/0j9wo15t/"

Comment: Though, I think, the question is self-explanatory. I just want to generate a grid line on the subchart. Thanks, for your help.